# Bash: How to grep in a list of files (some of which are zip files)

Tags: bash

I have a list of files i search for at high level, some .txt and some .gz

Each file is a text file under the hood.

Is there a command to find a obtain the list and grep each file? My attempt thusfar

```
find $(pwd) -name "instr.txt" -o -name "instr.txt.gz"
```

Comment: It is always advised to add samples of input and output into your post along with the efforts which you have put to fix this, kindly add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Might make more sense to do them separately.  For the txt files, you can do something like `grep <pattern> *.txt`.  You will need to extract the `.gz` files.  If you want to do it all as one process, save the list of files with `find` and loop through the list.

Comment: maybe using `zgrep` or `xzgrep`?

Comment: Yeah, `zgrep` works well for both plain text files and gz-archived text files. I wanted to propose a solution using a single `zgrep` command without `find` using `grep`'s `-r` and `--include` options but it turns out (my version of?) `zgrep` doesn't support them.

Answer (score 1):

`zgrep` will successfully search patterns in both plain text files and gz-archived files, so the following command should work fine :

```
find . \( -name "instr.txt" -o -name "instr.txt.gz" \) -exec zgrep searchedPattern {} +
```

A few notes :

- depending on the number of matched files, `zgrep` will or will not output the file name in addition to the matched lines. Use `-H` to force their presence or `-h` to force their absence.
- I've replaced the `$(pwd)` subshell by the equivalent relative path `.`, but this will impact the filenames in the output. If you need to output absolute pathes, using your subshell is fine.
- You need parenthesis to group the two sides of your `-o`, otherwise the action is only executed for the rightmost side. A less portable alternative would be to use `-regex 'instr.txt\(.gz\)?'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not doing this recursively (not searching through sub-directories), here is a simple solution that does not use `find`...

```
grep "insert pattern here" *.txt

for filename in *.gz; do
  zgrep "insert pattern here" "$filename"
done
```